# Can't find Einstein Activity Capture in personal settings, to connect calendar

Tags: einstein, calendar, google

I've enabled Einstein Activity Capture with G Suite for my org and now trying to connect a Google calendar. I've tried to follow the instructions to connect a calendar as described in [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.aac_connect_additional_accounts.htm&type=5), but can't find it under `Connected Accounts` in personal settings. Where do I go from here to connect a Google calendar with Einstein Activity Capture?

Thank you

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to assign the Standard Einstein Activity Capture permission set.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.aac_setup_assign_standard.htm&type=5